# Google cannot redirect to the URL I set, OAuth 2

Tags: php, redirect, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I am trying to use OAuth 2.0 to login Google. After I got the temporary authorization code and then use it to get the `access_token`, Google won't redirect me to the URL I set when post, here is the code I make post:

```
<form action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" method="post">
<input type="text" name="code" value='##code##'/>
<input type="text" name="client_id" value='##client_id##'/>
<input type="text" name="client_secret" value='##client_secret##'/>
<input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value='http://boomroom.tv/test.php'/>
<input type="text" name="grant_type" value='authorization_code'/>
<input type="submit" /></form>
```

After I got the access_token in JSON, it won't redirect me to my URL, but stay remain in the page 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no redirect involved in the [*exchange authorization code for an access token* step](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse). You should use a server side POST request here, where you get the *access token* and *refresh token* as a direct response. In your example the user's browser would send such a request, but not listen for its response.

Note that your *client secret* would be accessible publicly in your website's source code.

There are multiple ways to do a server side POST request with PHP, e.g. [using cURL](http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/).

Answer (score 1):

Jan's response is correct if you want to do this server-side.

If you want to handle things client-side in the browser, there's an separate OAuth 2 for Web Applications flow that you could use:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Client_Side_Web_Applications_Flow

The Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript makes it pretty easy to implement this:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication

And there's a live sample you could play with/borrow code from at:

http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html

Comment: Yep, correct ;) As the question was tagged with *php* I was only refering to the server-side flow which is more secure, but which flow is better suited obviously depends on the concrete use case.